# Printing the KeyMap pressed in zsh/bash

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh

Is there a way for zsh/bash to print out the keymap of the next received keystroke ?

I would press a key combination on my keyboard, and it would print, say

> keymap :
> `^A`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/bin/cat -v` will do what you want.

From cat(1) manpage :

> With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

```
    -v, --show-nonprinting
          use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this

[http://www.catb.org/~esr/showkey/](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/showkey/)

```
A simple keystroke visualizer

All this program does is read keystrokes and spit them back at you in
a simple, printable form. This is one of these silly little utilities
that you never think you'll need until some unexpected situation pops
up and you have to have it. Then you get to be mugged by the details
of tty-interface code, yippee. Never again!
```